# Adding question feeds to the chat room

Tags: discussion

It is possible to add feeds to the chat room. For example, a lot of sites like to add the meta site as a feed so that new meta questions show up on chat. It is also possible to follow a particular tag of another site and get alerts in chat whenever a new question with that tag is posted. It is even possible to add a feed with questions from the main site with a particular tag (e.g., if there is a problem tag that the community wants to watch for abuse).

In my experience too many feeds (or feeds that have too much activity) are annoying, but a few feeds can be helpful.

Are there any feeds that we should ask the mods to add into the main chat room?

Comment: Squish the feeds under your foot. *FEEDS SHOULD DIE*

Answer (score 3):

Please god no. Those feeds are awful. Keep chat for chatting and let people follow what they want.

Comment: Agree.  I think feeds would clutter up Chat.

Comment: And the people in the chat are the standard set of people who are anyway active. A link there by someone who thinks it's an interesting meta would be better than the horrible click to dismiss feed.

Answer (score 1):

I disliked having to dismiss the old notifications, and can't stand auto one-box feeds,

**but I have a left field idea that might work.**

We could **build a bot** that hits the api, and returns any new questions. Instead of using the feed, which would one-box them, it could write the messages like,

> New meta post [Adding question feeds to the chat room](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/adding-question-feeds-to-the-chat-room)

That way there isn't a one box for every single meta question, but they do get posted to chat. The other benefit of doing it with a purpose build bot, is that its **really easy to ignore a single user,** and so if someone didn't want to see the links, it would be easy for them to do so, while the lack of one boxes is much less annoying the lurkers.

Just an idea :)

Comment: The feed can be posted by a special user, I think, and may not need to be one boxed ( I don't know all the details of feeds).

Comment: @StrongBad There is this user on codereview https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-263/captain-obvious

Comment: This is a great idea! If I understand correctly, it would act just like any other  single line chat message, meaning it wouldn't take up much space and would be pushed back by new messages. It wouldn't have to wait for someone to put a link into chat. It could be a historical tool, to match chat discussions about things to when related meta questions get posted. Not all chatters are meta users but might be enticed if they see a new question. Enough attention would get a meta post featured on the main site, and attract new users, which I really want!